# How can I configure a Azure DevOps release Pipeline to use Universal Packages from Azure Artifacts?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

How can I configure a Azure DevOps release Pipeline to use Universal Packages from Azure Artifacts?
I can only choose a NuGet or npm package, but Universal Packages do not appear in the list.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure a Azure DevOps release Pipeline to use Universal Packages from Azure Artifacts?

As we know, the Universal Packages store one or more files together in a single unit that has a name and version. These packages are a lightweight, easy-to-use, and efficient way to transfer around a file or set of files, without the overhead of a traditional package manager with dependency management and other such features.

To use Universal Packages from Azure Artifacts in Azure DevOps release Pipeline, you could add the task **Universal package** to publish and download it:

[image]

After publishing the Universal Packages to the Azure Artifacts, you could use the Universal package task in the release Pipeline to download it from Azure Artifacts.

Check the document [Publish and download Universal Packages in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Leo's answer is correct today. You've highlighted a feature gap that we're addressing right now, which is support for Universal, npm, Maven, and Python packages in the "Azure Artifacts" artifact type in Release Management. Keep an eye on the release notes this month and next - we'll announce there when this gap is closed.

Comment: I'll wait for this feature flag, to be released.

Comment: I'll wait for this feature flag be released. The actual solution satisfy my needs in a 90% of the requirement.